# Does the rest of the party get buffed if one of their teammates disconnects?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing League of Legends and encountered my first instance of a teammate disconnecting and leaving the game (rather than a temporary disconnect). After I got over the momentary dread of being roffle-stomped, I played as normal and noticed that myself and my teammates (including one that I party with regularly) were doing surprisingly better than usual.

I've played custom maps in other similarly-styled games (StarCraft 2 custom maps that play like LoL/DotA, for example) where the rest of the group was made a bit stronger when someone left to compensate for the imbalance. Is that at work in League of Legends as well, or were we doing well without any additional help from the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no added buff when someone disconnects or leaves the game.
However, being alone on a lane gets you more experience and leaves all the monsters to you. As a result you can outlevel your opponents and get better stuff.

Comment: Aye, I'm aware about the benefit of being alone on a lane vs. with a teammate. The 4v5 went more in our favor than I felt that could account for, though.